# Ionic button-bar width on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a calendar widget for a phone application using angularjs + ionic and am noticing an issue in laying out the [ionic button bar](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#button-bar) on different screen sizes. Images near the end of the post.

The day names (sun, mon, etc.) are arranged using the standard grid options of `row` and `col`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="day in week">{{day}}</div>
</div>
```

The calendar is arranged using a `button bar` inside of a `row`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="button-bar">
        <div ng-repeat="c_day in cal_days">
            <a class="button">{{c_day}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I was expecting the button bar to auto fit the width of the screen just like `col` does in the day name row but, it is not. I tried playing around with `min-width` of the buttons but that did not help either.

Is there something I am missing?

Working as intended on iPhone 6:

[image: iphone 6 size]

Buttons overlapping on iPhone 5s:

[image: iphone 5s size]

Empty space on iPhone 6 Plus:

[image: iphone 6 plus size]

Comment: ok could you share a little more of your css?
What have you set for min-width ? 

the min width of the row and the button bar are all set to 100% ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis Am using all default css provided by ionic. I tried overriding `min-width` and using `button-small` but those things either don't work or just work well on one device.

Comment: ok what have you done to overwrite the min-width ?

One checking more do you include your css after the ionic css ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis I set `min-width: 44.28px` to see if that would make it fit on the iPhone 5s, but it didn't work. When I set the `min-width: unset` it just messed up everything. Yes, the custom css is at the end of all other css files.

Comment: ok the way is the good. you set the min-width of which class ? col ? row ? button-bar ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis I set it for the individual buttons i.e. the anchor tags. I tried over-riding the default button class and also tried introducing a custom class after the button class to override some properties like min-width and min-height.

Comment: ok but it's not your content that you have to set but your container.
for me you have to set the row width and the button-bar width to your expected width and then you will be able to set the button width

Comment: @jeremy-denis So, when I inspect the width for the parents `row` and `button-bar` they are taking the full width. It seems to be the button which is the issue.